# HP ProBook 440 G4 laptop black screen when SSD is attached

Tags: ssd, bios, black-screen-of-death

So I'm trying to install windows on my WD PC SN520 SSD  . However when I try to boot the laptop with the SSD attached , the fans start spinning but it's just a black screen.Not even the bios shows up.
Without the SSD the laptop boots to bios and even the windows installation media can be used . Just that it's completely non functional with the SSD attached.
I know the SSD is working because it works on my other system . So what could be the issue and how do I get it working.

Comment: It would help if you would give more detailed information. Like, what generation probook 440 and which SSD exactly ?

Comment: Edited the post to address the issues

Comment: Which SSD exactly? What brand and model and interface type?

Comment: As mentioned it's a WD sn520 nvme SSD for m.2 slot

Comment: Thank you for editing. Mystery solved, check the answer. If helpful please accept it. There's really nothing else to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HP ProBook 440 G4 supports M.2 SATA SSDs only. It isn't compatible with NVMe drives.**

According to the [HP ProBook 440 G4 specifications](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05273730#AbT4) it supports:

> M.2 (NGFF) 2280 solid state drive

"NGFF", in layperson's terms, is another name for SATA and that means it doesn't support NVMe drives and the symptom you're experiencing is the result of that, as expected. This specifications are also expected considering the hardware's age. Later generations of the same model had NVMe support.

Please note that both types fit the same M.2 slot but unless explicitly mentioned you can't use NVMe drives in any M.2.

Comment: Ohh , I had no idea that this was a thing . Well thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: It is indeed a thing. Please accept the answer.